# Selenium standalone server close browsers when losing connection and/or test manually killed

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a way to tell selenium server to automatically close browsers when I kill the running test, or if the connection is dropped between test and selenium standalone server ?

Comment: I vaguely remember that there is a class (can't remember class name) which you can extend and add the additional capabilities which you want..you will then have to add the newly extended class of yours in the classpath along with selenium-server while launching server

Answer (score 0):

You should quit the driver in your After method. This hook should always be called, even if the connection between the server and the test is lost.
If not it will wait until a certain timeout is reached before the driver gets killed.

Comment: I already have quit and close in my afterMethods. I want something to bind, when the test quits unexpected, like a stop from jenkins / either kill pid, because of this issues the browsers remains opened on remote test machine and I have to log in manually and click close.